# Sum pandas rows with same index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, sum

I have this kind of pandas, where the number of ids and elems isn't always the same. I need to sum rows with the same index, being the index the first position in every row. It's not always idx and different indexes don't share any pattern as they can be word, but I use idx as example. Original:

```
         elem1    elem2    elem3    nth_elem
    id1    4        2        6      ……
    id1    2        2        4      ……
    id1    1        6        8      ……
    id2    2        4        2      ……
    id2    6        8        6      ……
```

Desired output:

```
         elem1    elem2    elem3    nth_elem
    id1    7        10       18     ……
    id2    8        12       8      ……
```

I tried

> df.groupby(level=0).sum()

It orders the rows by id, but sum() is not working and I have the same pandas just ordered, with the same number of rows.

Any suggestions??

Comment: It's not the same situation and solution doesn't work. df.groupby(level=0).sum() orders the rows by index, but sum() does nothing and I keep the same number of rows

Comment: That solution does work; if it doesn't it's because your provided sample doesn't match your actual problem. Are you forgetting to assign the result back to something? That code will not modify `df`. Or do you have trailing whitespace in the `id` names, so that though they display the same they will never actually be grouped as `'id1' != 'id1 '`

Comment: Thanks @ALollz , it worked!! I wasn't re-assigning it, my mistake. Is there a way to replace all columns with only one column containing the mean per row??:

        mean    
id1    11,6 
id2    9,33

Comment: I think it's simplest to just do `df = df.groupby(level=0).sum()`. Whether you overwrite it or drop rows to collapse the values to one it really wont matter in the end, except the first is more readable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the correct answer